# How to add a CMake custom target for all submodules

Tags: cmake

Brief:
Does anyone know if it possible to add a custom_target in CMake that is included in all submodules?  An example would be how the Install/Run_Tests/Package targets are added to every submodule in a build.

More Detail:
My scenario is that for a directory structure such as:

```
Project
  --CMakeLists.txt
  --SubMod A
      --CMakeListsA.txt
  --SubMod B
      --CMakeListsB.txt
```

I would like to add a custom_target for doxygen generation to the top level CMakeLists.txt file and have that included in Sub Module A and B.  The command will be exactly the same between all modules.

I could add the custom_target to each sub-module's cmake file but this seems wrong.  The other issue with this is if I have CMake generate a Visual Studio solution there will be conflicts with a "doc" project already existing (if opening the top level solution).  CMake provided targets are however smart enough to not be included twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best you can do is wrap the `add_custom_target` in a function defined in your top-level CMakeLists.txt and use it in each CMakeLists.txt.

To avoid the problem of repeating target names, you could define the function something like:

```
function(AddDoxygenTarget)
  add_custom_target(Doxygen${PROJECT_NAME} ...)
endfunction()
```

This depends on each submodule's CMakeLists.txt having a `project` command.  If not, you could use each subdirectory's name:

```
  get_filename_component(SubDirName ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR} NAME)
  add_custom_target(Doxygen${SubDirName} ...)
```

Comment: Hmm, that does indeed solve most of the problem but not really ideal. However I am not entirely sure that there is a better answer which i kind of expected.

Comment: @JMcCarty Yeah, there may be a better way indeed.  I'd hold off and see if one of the Kitware guys chimes in.

Comment: Looks like no one else chimed in and this does accomplish what i wanted for the most part. Thanks